# Roaming profile is not loaded when user's password expires and is changed

Tags: windows-xp, domain, password, roaming-profile

Our password policy makes users change pw every 30 days, when this happens they sometimes find they are logged on with a local profile and none of their settings. This generally only happens when the PC was slow at logging onto the network, but in this case I know it had plenty of time to do so.

I can't work out why this is happening, is it related to a slow link?

Answer (score 0):

do you have a group policy that says to delete cached copies of roaming profiles or something?

Your description of the events doesn't seem to add up for me.

Comment: Yes that's what should happen, and it works most of the time. It may be that the two issues are completely unrelated, and the user's assertion about the password change is a red herring.